# Keras gradient wrt something else

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am working to implement the method described in the article https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s-qs-ivo_fJD9BU_tM5RY8Hv-opK4Z-H/view . The final algorithm to use is here (it is on page 6):

[image: Algorithm1]

- d are units vector
- xhi is a non-null number
- D is the loss function (sparse cross-entropy in my case)

The idea is to do an adversarial training, by modifying the data in the direction where the network is the most sensible to small changes and training the network with the modified data but with the same label as the original data.

I am trying to implement this method in Keras with the MNIST dataset and a mini-batch of 100 data, but I can't get my head around with the computation of the gradient wrt r (first line of the 3rd step of the algorithm). I can't figure out how to compute it with Keras. Here is my code :

```py
loss = losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()

for epoch in range(5):
    print(f"Start of epoch {epoch}")
    for step, (xBatchTrain,yBatchTrain) in enumerate(trainDataset):
        #Generating the 100 unit vectors
        randomVectors = np.random.random(xBatchTrain.shape)
        U = randomVectors / np.linalg.norm(randomVectors,axis=1)[:, None]

        #Generating the r vectors
        Xi = 2
        R = tf.convert_to_tensor(U * Xi[:, None],dtype='float32')

        dataNoised = xBatchTrain + R

        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as imTape:
            imTape.watch(R)
            #Geting the losses
            C = [loss(label,pred) for label, pred in zip(yBatchTrain,dumbModel(dataNoised,training=False))]

        #Getting the gradient wrt r for each images
        for l,r in zip(C,R):
            print(imTape.gradient(l,r))
```

The "`print`" line returns None for every sample. I should return me a vector of 784 values, each for one pixel?

(I apologize is part of the code is ugly, I am new to Keras, tf and deep learning)

[EDIT]

Here is a gist with the whole notebook: https://gist.github.com/DridriLaBastos/136a8e9d02b311e82fe22ec1c2850f78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, move `dataNoised = xBatchTrain + R` inside of `with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as imTape:` to recording the operation related to `R`

Second, instead of using:

```
for l,r in zip(C,R):
    print(imTape.gradient(l,r))
```

You should using `imTape.gradient(C,R)` to get sets of gradient, since `zip` will break the operation dependency in the tensor of `R`, print it out which will return something like following as same shape as `xBatchTrain`:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[-1.4924371e-06  1.0490652e-05 -1.8195267e-05 ...  1.5640746e-05
   3.3767541e-05 -2.0983218e-05]
 [ 2.3668531e-02  1.9133706e-02  3.1396169e-02 ... -1.4431887e-02
   5.3144591e-03  6.2225698e-03]
 [ 2.0492254e-03  7.1049971e-04  1.6121448e-03 ... -1.0579333e-03
   2.4968456e-03  8.3572773e-04]
 ...
 [-4.5572519e-03  6.2278998e-03  6.8322839e-03 ... -2.1966733e-03
   1.0822206e-03  1.8687058e-03]
 [-6.3691144e-03 -4.1699030e-02 -9.3158096e-02 ... -2.9496195e-02
  -7.0264392e-02 -3.2520775e-02]
 [-1.4666058e-02  2.0758331e-02  2.9009990e-02 ... -3.2206681e-02
   3.1550713e-02  4.9267178e-03]], shape=(100, 784), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: @Adrien PS: this just first problem I find, because your code cannot run so I cannot debug your code through, let me know if you have other problem

Comment: here is a gist with the whole notebook https://gist.github.com/DridriLaBastos/136a8e9d02b311e82fe22ec1c2850f78 I moved all the code in the `with` block, but I still get "`None`"

Comment: @Adrien I update the answer see if have other problem, PS: if you still have problem then I suggest you post a colab `.ipynb` link instead of github file link, so we can click and run your code

Comment: I thought of posting a collab but I didn't know for how much time they are available

Comment: @Adrien, Is OK, glad problem is solved : ) colab is very convenient, I basically just download your `.ipynb` file then upload it and run it.

Comment: I faced another issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65643459/keras-nan-value-when-computing-the-loss I am really uncomfortable with this whole thing of Keras + TensorFlow, the maths look much  easier ^^'

Comment: @Adrien , Now the time it's late, I'll take a look tomorrow, hope the problem can be solve before that